# Why do I get an 'undefined' error in regards to the data in my Angular template?

Tags: angular, templates, components, kendo-grid

I'm trying to create a template in my Angular 11 application but it's not recognizing the data inside it.

We have a Kendo grid, and we want the first column to consist of a button that brings up a menu when clicked. So I created a component to function as the button and the menu:

[image]

As you can see, we have 3 items in the menu. But there are some grids in our site which require more than just these 3 items. They require items that are unique to the grid. Rather than give the menu all the possible items a grid could need (and hide them if they're not needed), I'm trying to add them as a template to the menu from the component housing the grid.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="data" ... >
  <kendo-grid-column ... >
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>

      <!-- MY TEMPLATE -->
      <ng-template #customMenuItemsTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="dataItem.hpi?.id" ... >
          <mat-icon>...</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </ng-template>
    
      <!-- MY BUTTON & MENU COMPONENT -->
      <app-command-menu
        [contentTemplate]="customMenuItemsTemplate"
        [hpiId]="dataItem.hpi.id"
        ...
      ></app-command-menu>
      
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

As you can see, I define my template inside the grid (inside the kendoGridCellTemplate to be exact). I define it right before the app-command-menu component. I give the template a reference tag #customMenuItemsTemplate and use that reference to bind the template to [contentTemplate] in the command menu component. I add the template inside the grid so it knows what dataItem is. Yet I keep getting an error in the console saying:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hpi')`

Before I added the template, the application had no problem with dataItem. As you can see, I bind `dataItem.hpi.id` to `[hpiId]` in the command menu component. That was there before I added the template and it worked fine. Why would dataItem be defined for the component but not the template even though they're both exactly in the same place in the grid? Is it because the values in the template are only read from inside the component (i.e. after they are injected) as opposed to the page with the grid?

Please let me know if you need further examples of the code or more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was very simple. I had to remove `let-dataItem="dataItem"` from my template. So this:

```
<ng-template #customMenuItemsTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
...
</ng-template>
```

got converted to this:

```
<ng-template #customMenuItemsTemplate>
...
</ng-template>
```

I'm not sure why this worked. I would think setting dataItem with `let-dataItem="dataItem"` would be harmless at best, but apparently, it causes Angular to NOT know what dataItem is.